# While using JMeter's Html Assertion I m getting an error failure message - html assertion: can't parse argument number

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, assertion

Getting Error Failure msg: html assertion can't parse argument number
Http Request: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like a bug in JMeter you should report it via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

In the meantime if you need to use HTML Assertion you can downgrade to [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/)

Comment: have u checked this at your end.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue,

Just increase the warning threshold, in my case, more than 60 worked well.

And if you also want to see the warnings, create a text file, and add path in File name as shown in the screen shot below:

[image]

You will get all the warnings listed in the txt file that you have created. and at the end of file it will tell you how many warnings are there, just set warning threshold more than that.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file report.txt and specify the path to it in the filename field
At the end of the file you will find
InputStream: The document type "" is set
InputStream: The content of the document looks like transitional HTML 4.01
378 warnings and 40 errors were detected!
Increasing the number of threshold warnings and errors
The test is running successfully